# How do I ssh two deep with private keys?

Tags: ssh

At work, I can ssh to a server with private keys set up on my work machine.

```
jake@work$ ssh server
jake@server$
```

I'm trying to ssh from home to work to server with the private keys. The process should look like this:

```
jake@home$ ssh work
jake@work$ ssh server
jake@server$
```

But instead its asking me for a password. If I call ssh server with -v, it shows that its looking for keys .ssh/id_dsa and .ssh/id_rsa but my key is named differently.

I can get into server by specifying the key myself:

```
jake@home$ ssh work
jake@work$ ssh server -i .ssh/idfoo
jake@server$
```

How do I get ssh to find the right keys for this two step login process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the key using Host+IdentityFile in your ~/.ssh/config on `work`:

```
Host server
    IdentityFile idFoo
```

Or just this alone in the config file, to apply a key identity to all sessions:

```
IdentityFile idFoo
```

But I can't explain why this is required only when trying to ssh from `work`->`server` from a `work` ssh session.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but on my work station it would try all my identity files, but when I was ssh'ed in from somewhere else it would only try id_rsa, which I don't have. Listing all my identity files at the top of .ssh/config made it work. Thanks!